# -[UItableviewcell _setEditingStyle:]: message sent to deallocated instance

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I have a `UITextField` in my tableview cell. In the tableview class on Edit I am doing `[tableview setEditing:YES]` and on Done `[tableview setEditing:NO]`.

As I am have `- (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated` in the tableview cell I am using this method.

After pressing the Done button it is crashing on line `[tableview setEditing:NO]` and showing:

```
*** -[mycell _setEditingStyle:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x8d401b0
```

After seeing `po 0x8d401b0` it is giving `*** -[mycell respondsToSelector:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x8d401b0` .

How do I resolve this crash?

Code :

```
- (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setEditing:editing animated:animated];
    if(editing)
    {
        [self editModeActivated];
    }
    else 
    {   
        [self editModeDeactivated];
    }
}
```

Cell for rowatindexpath:

```
static NSString *identifier=@"cell";
mycell *cell = (mycell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];
if (cell == nil) 
{
    cell = [[mycell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:identifier]; 
}
```

And init code of cell

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"mycell" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
        [self customIntialization];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: Could you post the code of the tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: method of the UITableView dataSource?

Comment: your init method really looks crazy. cell reuse isnt working with this code.

Comment: Why it will not work as per ios 5 documentadn it is basic.we can access cell like this

Comment: This is Not Standart at all. How should reuse work, if the reuse identifier is never used. You should not bend a overwritten `initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier:` to load something from a nib. It should call its super-implementation.

Comment: But I dont have the resources to teach you how to deal with UITableView(Cell)s correctly in comments. Why dont you take your `initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier:` code, create a new question saying "this motherflipping jerk ikinci viking says this is wrong but he doesnt feel like he wants to deal with it in comments. What is wrong?"

Answer (score 0):

GOT the solution I just need to reload the table before setting [tableview setEditing:NO]. in done method

Comment: this sounds like something is broken

Comment: I think you have a problem in your `editModeActivated` or `editModeDeactivated`. I think reloading the table didn't really "fix" the problem.

Answer (score 0):

if you check tableviewcontroller editing property outside, you might need to reload table before table shown.